How to fit an image in a div, with a specific aspect ratio, keeping the same height/width as "natural"
Sorry, the title must be terrible to understand, but I don't know how to really explain it.
How can I fit my image "carouselMap" in the div "carouselItem", with an aspect ratio of 2/3, the width (of the map) being 100% of "carouselItem"'s width ?
I made a paint "drawing" to explain it.
<div class="carouselItem">
   <img class="carouselMap" src="../assets/myMap.png" />
</div>

.carouselItem {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.carouselMap {
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  width: 100%;
}


Thanks for your help 

change height: 100%; to height: auto; OR width: 100%; to width: auto;

Sorry my code was incomplete, but since I'm using "aspect-ratio", the width auto and height auto do not work

please add a shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question. at least the HTML part of this....

Is the map an image? If so, just style .carouselMap with object-fit: cover. This style causes an image (or any ‘replaced’ element) to be scaled to fill its specified dimensions by cropping itself in either the horizontal or vertical axis in order to retain its natural aspect ratio.
A snippet to demonstrate:


.carouselItem {
  width: 120px;
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.carouselMap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.rawImage {
  margin-top: 1em;
  width: 240px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
<div class="carouselItem">
  <img class="carouselMap" src="https://picsum.photos/id/58/500">
</div>

<img class="rawImage" src="https://picsum.photos/id/58/500">




It wasn't the solution, but it helped me find it thank you !

The solution was to create a div to contain the image, make it 100% of the width, give it an aspect ratio of 2/3, and put the image inside, center it, and give it a height of 100%
<div class="carouselItem">
   <div class="carouselImageContainer">
      <img class="carouselMap" src="/src/images/myImage.png" />
    </div>
</div>

.carouselItem {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.carouselImageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2/3;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carouselMap {
  height: 100%;
}

